# Does yum upgrade a package changes the configuration?

Tags: rpm, yum

I have a package name **package-1.0-12** which is already installed on my redhat machine. I did many configuration changes in the files (which are part of the RPM). Now, my manager want to upgrade it. Will all those configuration changes remain same or they get erase and new file will be updated?

Answer (score 2):

If the package has been constructed properly (i.e. the entry in `%files` has been tagged as `%config`) then files *intended for end-user configuration* will be left untouched and the configuration file from the new package will have ".rpmnew" appended to it. But back the file up regardless, since that's what you're supposed to be doing.